# Android Studio app:debugRuntimeClasspath

Tags: java, android, gradle

estoy pasando scripts de un proyecto de Android Studio a otro, ya que quiero reutilizar código. De momento no había tenido problemas, pero ahora no entiendo el motivo, no me resuelve las librerías "Volley" y todo lo que conlleva dentro de ellas. Mientras que en el proyecto original sí que las resuelve.

Les muestro el gradle del proyecto original:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kinder"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
}
```

Y ahora les muestro el gradle al cual le estoy pasando el código:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kinder"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
}
```

Como ven, las dependencias son idénticas (les hice copy paste), pero aun así, cuando pongo los implements en el .java, no me los resuelve:
[image: Error "Cannot resolve symbol 'volley'"]

No termino de entender el motivo por el cual se ha arreglado, pero es así, he borrado los implements del gradle, he sincronizado y entonces he vuelto a ponerlos y vuelto a sincronizar. Entonces, el error me ha desaparecido.

Pero aquí no acaba la cosa, ahora al darle al play, no compila y me aparece este error:`

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.`

He estado buscando información y muchos comentan que encendiendo y apagando el online del gradle ya se arregla, lo he probado pero no me funciona.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: En Android hay dos archivos gradle. Dinos en cuál estás poniendo la implementación. Quizá lo estás poniendo en el gradle que no es.

Comment: Estoy modificando el Gradle Module